# textfield is not recognized as a string in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table "Contracts" in access 2010 what is linked to SharePoint. There are  many fields from type text in this table. I would like to use this fields unsing the query "All-Contracts" in my VBA code but the These data from type text couldn't be  recognize as String, I get a runtime error"13:

```
Function funktion()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset 'All-Contracts
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim s as String
Dim CsrArray() As String

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("All-Contracts")

'Region is a field from type Text in The table "Contracts"

s = rs!Region  'runtime error "13: types incompatible 

CsrArray = Split(s)

For i = 0 To UBound(CsrArr) - 1  
....
```

Comment: Can you test with a recordset which does not contain the - character?

Comment: Do you mean with an other field which isn't  from type text?

Comment: I mean another field which does not contain the - character. "All-Contracts" contains it, so it is a good idea to test whether this - character is the problem.

Comment: "All-Contracts" is a query with many fields. I already tested your Idea. all fields are working. and some fields from type text too. just this one "Region".

Comment: Ok, so the problem is different. Let's see the next idea. Is Region as a column nullable? If so, are there values of null there?

Comment: yes its nullable but in the query all rows contain values

Comment: Then I believe that the type of s is String? and you need to convert it into String.

Comment: in SharePoint is "Region" from type CHOICE and as I export a linked table to access , "Region" has became automatically from type text

Comment: Can you try to convert it into String type? My guess is that it is of type String?, with the question mark at the end, marking that it is nullable.

Comment: I tried it as follow: s = CStr(rs!Region) ----> error 13

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I have reached to the conclusion that `Region` is `String?` since it is nullable. It needs to be converted to `String` using `CType` in order to be able to assign it to `s`. Also, I believe that the case when it is null should be handled as well, since it might well be the case that the fact that it is not null now is only a lucky coincidence.

The problem was that op referred to `Region` instead of `Region.Value`.

Comment: I tried it  as follow: s = CStr(rs!Region)      ---->  error 13

Comment: @otis, understood. What was the error message? Can you edit your question and paste the exact error you have?

Comment: @otis, can you put a breakpoint to that line and see what is the type of rs!Region and CStr(rs!Region)?

Comment: The problem was in the query itself, for "Region" there are two names in the DB. I should select "Region. Value" and not  "Region".